# Почему цвет RecyclerView отличается от фона?

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview

Фон `RecyclerView` почему-то выглядит немного более серым, чем фон, который стоит за ним. В чем может быть проблема? `android:background="@color/white"` у `RecyclerView` прописывал, но безрезультатно. Заметил, что если приподнять `RecyclerView` с помощью `translationZ` то он становится наоборот белее, чем задний фон. Вот как оно выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка `item'a`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationZ="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="23dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer_type"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mont_extra_bold"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mont_semi_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/timer_type"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/timer_type" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mont_extra_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/timer_type"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/timer_type" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Разметка `Activity`:

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/top_of_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background_top" />

            <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/scene_options"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/top_of_layout"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                    android:alpha="0.8"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/mont_extra_bold"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/quotes_timer"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="360dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

                <carbon.widget.Button
                    android:id="@+id/new_timer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/new_timer_button"
                    android:translationZ="100dp"
                    app:carbon_elevation="0dp"
                    app:carbon_rippleColor="@null" />

            </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

        </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: приложите разметку айтема и разметку экрана

Comment: @AVRamones добавил

Comment: это из-за CardView

Comment: @Wlad можно ли как-то починить этот `CardView` или лучше переделать без него?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать из CardView :

```
android:translationZ="100dp"
```

И добавьте

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Общий вид:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/card_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:cardCornerRadius="23dp"
  app:cardElevation="0dp">

...

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```